# What is the meaning of "square-ness" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Hush Puppies were a product of the 1950s, a decade often associated with “square-ness” and conventionality; therefore, it seems unlikely that such a shoe would become popular among young, hip people in the 1990s.

The definition on google is "quality of being square", but I can't understand how this meaning is fitting.

Comment: Would you mind providing the source of the quotation?

Answer (score 3):

The correct definition for *square* can be found in standard dictionaries, but perhaps buried too deeply to find easily:

> **square** adjective
>
> 5. f : being unsophisticated, conservative, or conventional

[*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square)

The following entry also provides an important context clue:

> **square** *adjective* (BORING PERSON)
>
> *old-fashioned informal*
>
> used to describe a person who is boring and does not like new and exciting things:
>
> - *Do you think my new haircut makes me look a bit square?*

[*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/square)

The clue there is the description, "old-fashioned."  *Square* is still occasionally used to mean *unhip*, but the term is not used nearly as much as it was in the past.  The fact that the term *square* is old-fashioned makes it especially appropriate to describe someone who was unhip in the 1950s.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, to be square or to be a square  means to be someone who is not cool or sophisticated in any way.

The condition of being square is thus squareness. ness=the state or condition of being something or of something

- looseness
- hardness
- coldness

The 1950's are seen as the time when everyone was pretty much the same. No one took a chance at being different. That was before the advent of the 1960's when this all changed dramatically with sex, drugs and rock n' roll (for example).

Merriam Webster:  **a person who is conventional or conservative in taste or way of life**